# How to modify Config in Laravel

Tags: laravel, config

I have a config file and this file contain this code lines

config/translatable.php

```
'locales' => [
    'en',
    'fr',
    'es' => [
        'MX', // mexican spanish
        'CO', // colombian spanish
    ],
],
```

I want to change this line to;

```
'locales' => [
    'en',
    'tr',
],
```

I tried third party packages but they don't support array config values.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to change config values for the current request, use `config()` helper:

```
config(['locales' => $languagesArray]);
```

If you want to change it and save it for the future requests, use 3rd party package, there are a plenty of packages which support arrays.

Comment: I don't want to change config values for the current request. I want to change the value for permanent. For example; When I go to project.dev/change route I want to change translatable.php's `locales` value.

Comment: @John as I said, in this case, you'll need to use the package. Or you could store this data in DB, so you can easily read and write it without using a package.

Comment: Okay, but I said, I used packages and packages don't support array. If you know any package for this issue, you could share with me.

Comment: @John https://github.com/OFFLINE-GmbH/laravel-config-writer/tree/master/src quick look into the code and I can see it checks if a value is a string or an array. There are plenty of other packages, use 'Laravel config writer' keyphrase to find other ones.

Comment: These packages don't support array .I can't add `['en', 'tr']`. `'item' => 'new value'` works but `'item' => ['value1', 'value2']` doesn't work.

Comment: @John what packages did you try?

Comment: https://github.com/daftspunk/laravel-config-writer
 https://github.com/OFFLINE-GmbH/laravel-config-writer
https://github.com/daftspunk/laravel-config-writer all of them.